# How do I exclude a tag from a search?

Tags: support, tag-search

I want to search only Google Maps tags and exclude "Android"

I wish to help out in answering `googlemaps` questions because I work with Google Maps in the Brazilian metro system.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search), and extrapolating off of the `+` referring to a guaranteed match for a tag, [you can use a search like `[google-maps] -[android]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps+-android) to search for questions that are tagged [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) and not with [android](/questions/tagged/android).

In general, you can use `-` to negate something in a search, whether it's a tag, a phrase, or anything.